# Is it possible to force run_list loading on shef's (chef shell) client mode

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

When debugging errors in chef recipes, I usually like logging on to a problematic machine, typing "shef -z". In the case that there was a previous successful run, the registered run_list is automatically loaded with all the relevant attributes and recipes so that I can jump right in to try the offending lines.

The problem is that if chef-client failed on the first run, the run_list is empty, and shef even deletes the (much needed) recipes from the cache saying "its cookbook is no longer needed on this client". Is there some way to force shef to let me use my run_list?

The official wiki [mentions:](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Shef)

> "The run list will be set in the same way as normal chef client
>   runs."

but trying "-j" doesn't seem to help.

I also tried running the solo mode ("-s -j") instead, as explained in this [blog post](http://blog.mycrot.ch/2012/02/07/chef-development-with-shef/). It loads the run_list (without expanding it, which is weird), but when I try to do anything, I get stuff like:

> "Cookbook tomcat not found. If you're loading tomcat from another
>   cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata".

Note that my recipe has a couple of dozen dependencies 3 levels deep, so pasting all the code manually to shef is not really an option. My current workaround is to upload a modified recipe with all possibly offending parts commented-out (and continue manually from there), but I would love to have a better alternative.

Comment: I imagine it doesn't expand the run list in solo mode as run list expansion is part of the Chef Server API interface (see the cookbook_versions POST under /environments) and requires some dependency solving code that possibly isn't possible with Chef solo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recipes aren't included by default when you start shef in client or solo modes, because a use case of shef is to determine why a recipe may not be loading at all, such as a compile time bug that causes some exception.

Therefore, you need to use include_recipe to include the recipes you wish to use. You can do this automatically for all the roles/recipes in the node's run list with:

```
node.run_list.expand(node.chef_environment).recipes.each do |r|
  include_recipe r
end
```

For more information on this, and a bunch of other great tips for using Shef to debug chef-client runs, see [Steven Danna's blog post](http://stevendanna.github.com/blog/2012/01/28/shef-debugging-tips-1/)

Comment: Thanks, it was a great post to read.
At first try, I still got the same "Cookbook xyz not found" errors, since the run list wasn't yet populated for this node, but then I  reread "_We can only use include_recipe on recipes that Shef downloaded when we started it up_" and then it hit me.

I loaded the run_list manually with `knife node run_list add` and then running just `shef -z` works well without the need to pass a run_list in json.

Comment: Need to use `node.run_list.expand(node.environment, 'disk')` for chef solo

Answer (score 0):

When Chef runs for the first time, it creates /etc/chef/first-boot.json file with run list inside. Try running:

```
shef -z -j /etc/chef/first-boot.json
```

Comment: Nope, as I mentioned above, this doesn't load anything for me (but does work partially in "-s" mode).
In case it matters, I'm now using version 10.12.0, but I remember this behavior from other versions, too. Does it work for you?